# Compare dataframes in scala and write the mismatching old and new columns to new dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two df's

df1
ID |BTH_DT    |CDC_FLAG|CDC_TS                       |CNSM_ID
123|1986-10-07|I       |2018-10-10 05:51:24.000000941|301634310
124|1973-02-15|I       |2018-10-10 17:12:22.000000254|298910234

df2
ID |BTH_DT    |CDC_FLAG|CDC_TS                       |CNSM_ID
123|1986-10-07|I       |2018-10-10 05:51:24.000000941|\c
124|1973-02-15|I       |2018-10-10 17:12:22.000000254|298910234

How do i compare two df's and write the mismatching columns alone to different df?

ID |CNSM_ID
123|301634310
123| \\c

```
df2.except(df1)
```

above isn't serving the purpose

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
val diff1=df1.except(df2)
val diff2=df2.except(df1)
val join=diff1.unionAll(diff2)
```

Then `join.select("id","CNSM_ID")`.

Comment: This doesn't give the old and new values and not all the times CNSM_ID is the only field that mismatches, it might be BTH_DT |CDC_FLAG|CDC_TS |CNSM_ID and many more in that table

Comment: Oh ok, I thought it was only one mismatching column